# Why is iOS not summoning terminated apps for location updates?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

Please take a look at this [extremely simplified basic app](https://github.com/Ludotrico/LocationTest) I just made with one VC to illustrate the problems with location services in iOS.

Despite having background modes enabled in the app plist, having "always" location permissions enabled, configuring a singleton CLLocationManger objects and a delegate correctly, and calling startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges(), the app is never launched by the system when it is in a terminated state.

In the [sample app](https://github.com/Ludotrico/LocationTest) I just built to illustrate the problem, if the app was launched, the counter on the screen would increase, but it never does.

Does anyone with iOS location services experience understand what is going wrong in an otherwise error-free approach?

Sample App:

https://github.com/Ludotrico/LocationTest

Comment: User ultimately decides if the app should run. If user kills the app, it should really mean that user <<kills>> the app. There should be no any long-running actions remaining after user does that. That are the reasons behind this behavior.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk according to apple this is not the case https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background many apps use location after the user kills the app.

Comment: The background mode execution happens rarely for a short period of time when system thinks it is necessary. I suppose, for `Location updates` it would be logically that it happens only if location has indeed significantly changed. App does not become a system daemon that constantly receives location updates ignoring the user willing to kill it.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk any references to back up this claim? I can name several apps that constantly receive location updates even with the app being terminated (eg. life360).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence

Comment: Also, on the page that you've shared, there is a table `Table 1 Services that relaunch your app after it has been terminated`. In that table, it is stated that only `Significant-change location service`, `Visits service` and `Region monitoring` can launch the app.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk exactly. Did you take a look at the sample app I made to illustrate the problem? I called startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

Comment: But did you trigger the significant location change itself in order to get the callback?

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk yes, I drove around my city.